# How to watch the different key in a same array in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a code like below.

```
data():{
   coor: [
          { "name": '',
            "shoes": '' },
          { "name": '',
            "shoes": '' }       
         ]

watch:{
   coor: {
       handler(){
          console.log('changed')
       }
       ,deep: true
   }
}
```

In this case if whichever value in coor is changed, watch works.
But my goal is I want to make the case divided by two like below.

```
watch:{
       coor.name: {
           handler(){
              console.log('The name is changed')
           }
           ,deep: true
       },
       coor.shoes: {
           handler(){
              console.log('The shoes are changed')
           }
           ,deep: true
       }
    }
```

But it doens't work well. How can I solve this problem? Thank you so much for reading.

Comment: your coor.name and coor.shoes is undefined... it should be coor[0].name... but that is hardcoded solution and not good...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a computed property of the items you want to watch, and watch that instead.

```
computed {
  filteredAny(){
    return this.coor;  
    // you can also use map here and combine values to create a key.
    // return this.coor.map(it=>it.shoes+':'+it.name)
  },
  filteredShoes(){
    return this.coor.map(it=>it.shoes);
  },
  filteredName(){
    return this.coor.map(it=>it.name);
  }

}

watch {
  // deep not needed.
  filteredShoes(){
    console.log('The shoes are changed');
  }

}
```

Comment: Could you write the code exactly? I dont't understand well by just text.

Comment: I have a question. Your code works when I typed, "return this.coor.filter(it=>it.name === 'name');" . Than is it has to add "it.name" not "it". But How can I modify for the any case?

Comment: I am going to update the solution based on your comment.  Let me know if it works.